# Is there a Python version of .h and .cpp files?

Tags: python, c++

In C++ there are .h and .cpp files for design and implementation of code respectively. Is there a similar way to structure files in Python? Can I define my class in one file, and then put all the code for that class in another?

I feel like the answer is "no". I've tried looking up the answer, but the closest results were just how to merge c++ and python.

Comment: No, python is an interpreted language, and as such it doesn't `link` files in some kind of compilation. Everything has to be in the same place.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The only reason it has to be done this way in C++ is because of the way the compiler works and it is arguably pretty annoying having to split things up this way

Comment: No, you can't do that - the two languages are almost completely different.

Comment: If you want to feel like you're writing C++, there are type stub files. They do something completely different from what C++ header files do, but maybe writing them will make you feel better, and they're a lot better than some other writing-C++-in-Python things you might do.

Comment: No there's isn't because it's not necessary. The closest thing occurs when you `import some_module` which is similar to `#include` in C++ (only it used to process `.py` files, such as `some_module.py`).

Comment: Woah woah woah! I was just asking a question. Why down vote the post? I find it much easier to understand what a program is doing if I can just see the functions a program has without it getting bogged down by the actual code. Do you guys disagree? If so, why?

Also, thank you @AlexG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much less worthwhile to do than in c++ because as AlexG mention python is not a compiled language. However, you could achieve a "similar" effect by linking to another python file. For example, if you wanted to have all of your functions created in a single file, and all of your logic done using those functions in another you would simply use `import filename` and you could reference your functions in the second file like you would in a .h and .cpp file.